# Fake USB 2.0 to be 3.0

Tags: usb, usb-3

I've got kind of a strange question: is it possible to make a USB 2.0 port look like an USB 3.0 port to any attached device? (Linux or Windows, does not matter)

Background: I've got a capture card for video signals which SHOULD work with USB 2 (bandwith should be enough), but the device requires USB 3 before even starting up.

Are there any chances that I tell that device its connected as designed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure this would work - but have you tried plugging a powered USB 3 hub into the USB 2 port? What sort of "capture card" is it? Does it need the higher power supplied through USB 3?

Comment: Short answer: no.  Even if you built a device to fake USB 3.0, the device would try to connect via USB 3.0 and fail.  Your only hope would be if it's just a power issue, in which case DrMoishe Pippik's idea of using a powered USB 3.0 hub might work.  That would supply more power, but still make a USB 2.0 connection to a USB 2.0 computer port, and that would be the only data connection available in the hub..

Comment: If is unclear what your question is. If a device is USB3, it will connect as USB3 first in a USB3 port, regardless if USB2 bandwidth is enough or not. Is your device a USB3 device? What do you mean by "device requires USB3"? DO you mean that it doesn't work if plugged into a USB2-only port?

Comment: The device checks what kind of port it is connected to and reports an error to windows event log that it does not work with USB 2.0. So my hope was to fake a 3.0 port by sending false information to that device on connection.

I was just curious about wether it is possible to do that, nothing critical. Gonna get an 3.0 PCI card after holidays.